# Combobox items based on input from two other comboboxes

Tags: c#

Hi I have an access table called equipment table and a win form with multiple comboboxes the first three work but they are getting distinct values from the Access table. The third however is receiving input from the comboboxes Manufacturer_cmbBx and Type_cmbBx which work.  I have used the same code for all the comboboxes and only the Select query has changed. The Diagnostic tool in VS shows that the right values are being passed into the Select query. yet the combobox remains empty. I have called for the combobox to be changed on the SelectedValueChanged event of the combobox Type_cmbBx

```
     private void LoadModel_cmbBx()
    {

        string strCon = Properties.Settings.Default.Database2ConnectionString;
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
        {
            try
            {
                string strSql = "Select Model from EquipmentTable where [Manufacturer] = '" + Manufacturer_cmbBx.Text + "' and [Type] = '" + Type_cmbBx.Text + "'";
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(strSql, conn));
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                Model_cmbBx.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                Model_cmbBx.ValueMember = "Model";
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the data contained in `ds.Tables[0]` look like?  Does it contain multiple columns?

Comment: The EquipmentTable has the columns ID, Manufacturer, Model, Type and PartNumber. Since The DataSet ds is based on the EquipmentTable it should contain the same. But I have no idea how to check.

Comment: I would try putting the data in a `List<>` first to troubleshoot what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Using The Dataset Viewer in VS I could see that only the Model column was in there so I changed my statement to

```
  "Select DISTINCT * from EquipmentTable where Type  = '" + Type_cmbBx.Text + "' and Manufacturer = '"+ Manufacturer_cmbBx + "'";
```

This still didn't work but

```
    "Select DISTINCT * from EquipmentTable where Type  = '" + Type_cmbBx.Text + "'";
```

Works as does

```
     string strSql = "Select DISTINCT * from EquipmentTable where Manufacturer = '" + Manufacturer_cmbBx + "'";
```

only when I try to add a second combobox does the Dataset remain empty. Any thoughts as to why this is?